# Replacing elements in a list if contains X (string)

Tags: replacement

I want to replace T1 with T2 if the list contains X (It's a string with something more) or else return unevaluated.

**Input:**`list={{1,Y 25,T1},{2,Y 26 V, T1},{3, X 25 D, T1}}`

**Output:**`{{1,Y 25,T1},{2,Y 26 V, T1},{3, X 25 D, T2}}`

*I have tried this:*

```
  If[MemberQ[{list}, "X"], Replace["T1" -> "T2"], 
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

Comment: In your list, `X` is not a string, but a variable, correct?

Comment: It's a string (with something else), that's why I am having trouble.

Comment: So when I copy your input, it doesn't come as a string

Comment: Is every element of the list a string?

Comment: Maybe Replace[list, T1 -> T2, {2}]?

Comment: Every element of the list is a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"1", "Y 25", "T1"}, {"2", "Y 26 V", "T1"}, {"3", "X 25 D", 
    "T1"}};


If[StringContainsQ[ToString@#, "X"], # /. "T1" -> "T2", #] & /@ list
(* {{"1", "Y 25", "T1"}, {"2", "Y 26 V", "T1"}, {"3", "X 25 D", "T2"}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{"1", "Y 25", "T1"}, {"2", "Y 26 V", "T1"}, {"3", "X 25 D", 
    "T1"}};
If[Or @@ StringContainsQ["X"][#], 
   StringReplace["T1" -> "T2"][#], #] & /@ list
```

> {{"1", "Y 25", "T1"}, {"2", "Y 26 V", "T1"}, {"3", "X 25 D", "T2"}}

Comment: Note for OP: the `StringReplace` would also change "T1 r" to "T2 r" whereas a `Replace["T1"->"T2"]` as in the question would not. This might be desired, might not or might be irrelevant depending on the lists the code will be used for.